# Rsync interruption

Tags: repository, rsync, mirrors

I started a `rsync` operation with:

```
rsync -a --bwlimit=128 --progress rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu /media/8GB/ubuntu
```

It was interrupted.

What do I have to fix if I reissued the command again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change anything.  Rsync starts by examining the source and destination files, to find those which have been updated and need to be copied to the destination:

> Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that
>          have  changed  in  size  or  in  last-modified time.  Any changes in the other preserved attributes (as requested by
>          options) are made on the destination file directly when the quick check indicates that the file’s data does not need
>          to be updated.

If you have interrupted the prior Rsync command, what has happened is that not all of the files which needed to be copied, have been, and they will appear in the new iteration of Rsync.

Comment: This is why I love it so much!